# Implementation of a terminal history functionality in a tiny toy project

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to emulate a specific feature of terminal emulators, the ability to parse through previous commands.

My real naive approach was to try and create a cyclical buffer and navigate through it with a next and prev command where it essentially changes view to the current line in the history buffer.

```
typedef struct {
    char buffer[GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE][GT_SCQUEUE_STRING_SIZE];
    int front;
    int rear;
    int view;
} GT_SCQueue;

GT_SCQueue scq = {{{0}}, -1, -1, 0};

void GT_SCQueue_Push(GT_SCQueue* scq, const char* string) {
    if (++scq->rear == GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE) {
        scq->rear = 0;
    }

    if (scq->front == scq->rear) {
        scq->front = (scq->rear + 1) % GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE;
    }

    if (scq->front == -1) {
        scq->front = 0;
    }

    strncpy(scq->buffer[scq->rear], string, GT_SCQUEUE_STRING_SIZE - 1);
    scq->buffer[scq->rear][GT_SCQUEUE_STRING_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Not at all workable, my code has gotten messy and I'm about to do a rewrite, what are some ways of implementing this feature? is a cyclical buffer the correct way to do this? I wasn't sure how to place the constraints on the functions that traverse up and down the buffer. I'm more so looking for ideas and simple resources/implementations of the desired feature.

Comment: Something like your code can work. Please note that you are wasting a lot of memory if your GT_SCQUEUE_STRING_SIZE is large, but the typical history entry is short. To avoid that, you can allocate each entry separately with malloc(...). Alternatively, you can have a single, big, cyclic `char[...]` array, and you can limit the history by byte instead of entry count, but this is more complicated to implement.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that lends itself to a linked list best, imo.  You could use an array of X indexes if you can be SURE that your user wont need more than X instances of command-line history.  But a linked list can be added to indefinitely.  Speaking of that, I wonder now if linux or windows have a limit on count of command-line history?  If there is a limit, then you could be personally comfortable with a queue as you've got now.

Comment: If your code doesn't work as expected, this website (StackOverflow.com) is indeed the right place to ask for help. However, to make it possible for us to help you fix your code, please write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the failure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm aware of the potential memory waste there. For now I'd like to avoid implementing anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is how you can implement a stack solution in your code.
I've not found use for structure members `front, rear, view` but I left them intact in the structure.  Perhaps my addition of global variable `stack_top` replaces the intent of one or two of those structure members?

I'm not a fan of globals, but a stack pointer (`stack_top`) needs to be shared by two functions, so here we are.  You can certainly code it differently if a global is too horrible.  It can certainly be added as a member of GT_SCQueue, and that is an easy mod, yes?

Tested, runnable code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/bfr4bfr5o

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


#define GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE 1000

/* Only one modification to the structure ... */
typedef struct {
    char *buffer[GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE]; /* ... here. */
    int front;  /* unused */
    int rear;   /* unused */
    int view;   /* unused */
} GT_SCQueue;


GT_SCQueue scq = {{0}, -1, -1, 0};
int stack_top = -1;

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GT_SCQueue_Push()

    Places the item in param string onto the stack.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int GT_SCQueue_Push(GT_SCQueue* scq, const char* string) 
{
    if(stack_top < GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE-1)
    {
        stack_top++;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow items: %d  Max: %d .... moving 1st item out of stack.\n", stack_top+1, GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE);
        return 0;
    }
    /*Add new item on the right */
    scq->buffer[stack_top] = strdup(string);

    if(!scq->buffer[stack_top])
    {
        printf("GT_SCQueue_Push() memory error!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("GT_SCQueue_Push() added element [%s].  Elements on the stack: %d  Available: %d\n", 
            string, stack_top+1, GT_SCQUEUE_SIZE-(stack_top+1) );

    /* Return success */
    return 1;
}


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GT_SCQueue_Pop()

    Pops an item off the stack and into param string.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int GT_SCQueue_Pop(GT_SCQueue* scq, char *string) 
{
    if(stack_top < 0)
    {
        printf("UNDO Stack Underflow -- index: %d", stack_top);
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(string, scq->buffer[stack_top] );
    free(scq->buffer[stack_top]);
    scq->buffer[stack_top] = NULL;
    printf("GT_SCQueue_Pop() popped element index: %d of string [%s]\n", stack_top, string);
    stack_top--;
    return 1;
}

int main() 
{
char b1[20];

    GT_SCQueue_Push(&scq, "Hello You!");
    GT_SCQueue_Pop(&scq, b1);
    printf("Report from main() -- Popped [%s]\n", b1);
}
```

Output:

```
    T_SCQueue_Push() added element [Hello You!].  Elements on the stack: 1  Available: 999
    GT_SCQueue_Pop() popped element index: 0 of string [Hello You!]
    Report from main() -- Popped [Hello You!]
```

Comment: @Grae - here is a stack solution you can implement quickly and easily (I hope).  If this works out for you, please consider selecting my answer.  Cheers -